# Interpolating time ordered smooth function into space

Tags: time-series, generalized-additive-model, interpolation, generator

I am using GAMs in R to generate daily weather variables, mainly precipitation and temperature. Currently, I am fitting a model for each weather station but I would like to use it in places where there is no available data. Until now I've been using a GLM based model where coefficients can be interpolated into space fairly easy. One of my models is the following

```r
tx_fit <- mgcv::gam(tx ~ s(tx_prev, tn_prev, by = estacion.factor) +
    prcp_occ + prcp_occ_prev +
    s(mean_tx, mean_tn, by = estacion.factor) +
    s(doy, bs = 'cc'),
  select = TRUE,
  correlation = corARMA(form = ~ 1|year),
  data = matriz.ajuste[indice.tx,],
  method = "REML",
  control = list(nthreads = cl))
```

Where tx is the current day's max temperature, tn_prev and tx_prev are the previous day's temperature, prcp_occ is precipitation occurrence, mean_tx and mean_tn are seasonal averages and doy is the day of the year. This model is fitted to each station in the network. Each smooth function is a non-parametric function so I don't have any coefficients in order to rebuild it somewhere else. Besides each station has its own function. 
The functions are like this:

[image: This corresponds to the last term of my model, the effect of doy]

And interactions are like this:

[image]

Seasonal averages will be interpolated to a regular grid and so will be the first value of the simulation.

I've thought of fitting a new spline to the smooth function retrieved by the gam but I am still not sure how to interpolate it into space. Do you have any ideas on how could this be done?

Can fixing the number and positions of the knots be of any help?

If sample data can be of help, I will post it right away!

Thank you very much and I apologise beforehand for my English!

My best,

Alessio

UPDATE: 16/09/2019

I've created a folder in Goggle Drive where I've uploaded the code I've used to fit the models and some sample data.

[Code and sample data](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kLjRJ01rZDpRe8sqLqyeH0vQ_V4_YUHa?usp=sharing)

Comment: why can't you easily extrapolate the GAM model? Is it not possible to use the predict.gam function from mgcv?

Comment: You should probably do the modelling inside the GAM to interpolate the smooth spatially. It's not true that you don't have coefficients; see `coef(model)`. those are the weights for each basis function used in each smooth and are what control/define the shape of the estimated spline. You'd need to interpolate the in groups, but you could do it. Better would be to model how the shape of the smooth varies spatially, but that might not be possible with your set-up/data?

Comment: Note your model is entirely ignoring `correlation = corARMA(form = ~ 1|year)`. For that to have any effect you need to fit via `gamm()`.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Thank you very much for your comments. I was thinking about fixing the number of basis per station/variable and then interpolating the weights into space. Could I reconstruct the smooth functions in each new point? My first approach was to use a natural cubic regression where the knots are placed in certain quantiles of each variable and then rebuilding the smooth function using the interpolated values of each new knot but that hasn't been succeeded yet! How could I model the shape of the spline? Sorry for all the questions. Thank you very much indeed! Regards.

Comment: What is `estacion.factor` the weather station? This is going to be problematic. It's like you had a fixed effects models for levels 1 through 5 and now want to predict for level 6 and 7. You would need to either model those terms as random smooths or use a global smooth plus random smooths. Colleagues and I discussed this in a recent paper: https://doi.org/10.7717/peerj.6876. Alternative;y, you drop the `by` factor and you model how the smooth varies as a function of space: `s(tx_prev, tn_prev, x, y, d = c(2,2))` where each is a 2d thin plate regression spline.  1/2

Comment: Where the second pair of coordinates assume you can treat space isotropically. That smoother will need a lot of data are reasonable density in space to be estimable.

Comment: Dear @GavinSimpson. Thank you for your comments. `estacion.factor` just accounts for the season. Perhaps I could use four dummy variables, one for each season of the year instead. I'll read your paper right away! So instead of fitting a model for each station, you suggest a single model where I take into account the spatial dependency between weather stations? 

So, interpolating the weights of the basis and then reconstruct the smooth functions somewhere else isn't an option, right?